# Closed form for a recurrence relation $(p^n-p^{n-1})p^{n(k-1)}+p^{n-1}a_{k-1}=a_{k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

So I'm a bit rusty with recurrence relations and I was wondering if someone could help me with this. I'm basically trying to calculate the number of elements of order $p^n$ in a specific group and I got the following recursive relation $$(p^n-p^{n-1})p^{n(k-1)}+p^{n-1}a_{k-1}=a_{k}$$
Note that $n$ is a fixed value in this case. I would really appreciate any help I can get trying to find a closed form for the above expression.

Comment: You mean, this should hold for every $(n,k)$? Or for every $n$, for some fixed $k$? Or the other way round?

Comment: $n$ is a fixed value in this case

Comment: Then rewrite this as $$\frac{a_k}{p^{(n-1)k}}=\frac{a_{k-1}}{p^{(n-1)(k-1)}}+[\text{some term}]$$ iterate, and rejoice.

Comment: I'm still having issues. The formula I end up with is $$\frac{a_k}{p^{(n-1)k}}=\frac{a_{k-1}}{p^{(n-1)(k-1)}}+\frac{p^n-p^{n-1}}{p^{n-k}}$$ which isn't a linear recurrence relation.

Comment: @Did could you help me out please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$\frac{a_k}{p^{(n-1)k}}
=\frac{a_{k-1}}{p^{(n-1)(k-1)}}+\frac{p^n-p^{n-1}}{p^{n-k}}
$,
let
$b_k
=\frac{a_k}{p^{(n-1)k}}
$.

Then
$b_k
=b_{k-1}+cp^k
$,
where
$c
=\frac{p^n-p^{n-1}}{p^{n}}
=1-\frac1{p}
$.

Therefore
$b_k-b_{k-1}
=cp^k
$.
Summing from
$k=1$ to $m$,
$b_m-b_0
=c\sum_{k=1}^{m} p^k
=(1-\frac1{p}) \frac{p^{m+1}-p}{p-1}
$
so
$b_m
=a_0+ (1-\frac1{p})\frac{p^{m+1}-p}{p-1}
$
and you can get
$a_m
=p^{m(n-1)}\left(a_0+(1-\frac1{p}) \frac{p^{m+1}-p}{p-1}\right)
=p^{m(n-1)}\left(a_0+p^m-1\right)
$.